# Keep transition effect on 1 div from moving the div that follows?

Tags: hover, position, css-transitions, margin

**1.** I have a 4 column row of divs that move a little when hovered (with margin and padding).  How can I keep this movement from  moving the content that is below it *without adding a fixed height*.  It is in a fluid layout so with a fixed height that allows enough room for the movement, the content below starts to get too far away as the window width is reduced and the images scale down.

**2.** For the bounty you need to make the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/ZuU8V/2/) work.

It seems that even though I have `transition: all`, *all* of the padding-bottom gets added instantly while the margin-top transitions for 300ms.  Shouldn't the padding transition also? I think that would get rid of the jump.  I tried transitioning height on hover for the same effect but it had the same exact issue. the height just got added instead of transitioning.

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/ZuU8V/2/) to play with.

HTML:

```
<header class="sectionTitle lightboxes clearfix">
     <h3><i class="i-small icon-folder-open"></i><strong>Portfolio</strong></h3>
</header>
<article id="row2fluid" role="presentation">
    <section id="row2col1"> <a class="slider" href="#"><img src="http://mtctinc.com/images/folioImg1.jpg" alt="porfolio 1" />
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Example 1</h3>
                <span>Slider/Slideshow</span>
            </div>
         </a>   
    </section>
    <section id="row2col2"> <a class="youtube" href="#"><img src="http://mtctinc.com/images/folioImg2.jpg" alt="portfolio 2" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Example 2</h3>
                    <span>Youtube</span>
                </div>
                </a>

    </section>
    <section id="row2col3"> <a href="#" class="clearfix"><img src="http://mtctinc.com/images/folioImg3.jpg" alt="porfolio 3" />
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Example 3</h3>
                        <span>Flash</span>
                    </div>
                    </a>

    </section>
    <section id="row2col4"> <a href="#" class="clearfix"><img src="http://mtctinc.com/images/folioImg4.jpg" alt="portfolio 4" />
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Example 4</h3>
                            <span>HTML</span>
                        </div>
                        </a>

    </section>
</article>
<div id="moreContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget nulla laoreet, blandit massa eu, mollis tellus. Duis pellentesque dui nec diam ullamcorper, ac dignissim sapien interdum. Proin in libero nec neque fermentum varius. Integer hendrerit, justo feugiat porttitor iaculis, nisl purus luctus neque, non ultrices magna quam et magna. Proin porttitor, metus sed commodo pharetra, lacus eros aliquet diam, eu auctor nisi diam quis felis.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sectionTitle {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e9e9e9;
    width:100%;
}
.sectionTitle h3 {
    font-size:11px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3b3b3b;
    display:table;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 33px;
    line-height: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.sectionTitle strong {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left:10px;
    line-height:14px;
}
.lightboxes {
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#row2fluid {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#row2fluid img {
    opacity: .8;
    border: none;
    -webkit-transition:all 300ms;
    -o-transition:all 300ms;
    -moz-transition:all 300ms;
    transition:all 300ms;
}
#row2fluid a:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
#row2fluid a:hover .caption h3 {
    color: #F15A2B;
}
#row2fluid .caption {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    margin: 0px 3px;
    line-height: .7em;
    padding: 14px 0 30px;
}
#row2fluid a:hover .caption {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F15A2B;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    padding-bottom: 46px;
}
#row2fluid .caption span {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ACACAC;
}
#row2col1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 24.1758%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
#row2col2 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.0989%;
    width: 24.1758%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
#row2col3 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.0989%;
    width: 24.1758%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
#row2col4 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.0989%;
    width: 24.1758%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
#row2col1:hover {
    border-top: 3px solid #F15A2B;
    padding-top: 37px;
}
#row2col2:hover {
    border-top: 3px solid #F15A2B;
    padding-top: 37px;
}
#row2col3:hover {
    border-top: 3px solid #F15A2B;
    padding-top: 37px;
}
#row2col4:hover {
    border-top: 3px solid #F15A2B;
    padding-top: 37px;
}
#moreContent {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add
`-webkit-transition:all 300ms;
-o-transition:all 300ms;
-moz-transition:all 300ms;
transition:all 300ms;`
to the caption as well.

See here
http://jsfiddle.net/ZuU8V/4/