# Multilevel Nav Menu not showing 3rd level

Tags: html, css, overflow, transition

the third level of my menu doesn't show up when hovering the 2nd level.  I know that this is because `overflow:hidden` is styled on the 2nd level `ul`, however, if I make `overflow:visible` then the transition effect with `max-height` doesn't work properly.  I have tried making `overflow-y:hidden` with `overflow-x:visible` and that does allow the transition to still work but adds a horizontal scroll bar that you need to scroll to the right to see the 3rd level menu.  If you can solve this, i have another question with a bounty on it that I have only gotten 1 poor answer on: [BOUNTY QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448488/keep-transition-effect-on-1-div-from-moving-the-div-that-follows)

[My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/Us9rx/41/) and the relevant code below:

```
#menu li >  ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:auto;
    left:0;
    width:180px;
    max-height:0;
    box-shadow:1px 2px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index:99999;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
     -moz-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
     -o-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
     -ms-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
     transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
  background: inherit !important;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: 216px;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
#menu li > ul > li > ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:0 !important;
  left:180px !important;
  width:180px;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow:1px 2px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

html:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul id="main-nav">
        <li id="port"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="regular"><a href="#">Regular</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="4col"><a href="#">4 columns</a>
                        </li>                        
                    </ul>
                </li>                
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="about" class="parent menu-item"><a href="">About</a>            
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow:visible` when hovering over the `ul` element. In doing so, the transition will still take place because the overflow is hidden prior to hovering over the element.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rkV34/)

```
#menu ul li > ul:hover {
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: sweet! that was fast. Do you know why that `ul` now changes size on hover?

Comment: I had asked this question over a week ago worded slightly different and it sat until today without so much as a comment. thank you  for this

Comment: @ChrisM It's because padding is added to the element on hover. Prior to changing the overflow to `visible`, the excess padding would be hidden. To solve this, simply add `box-sizing:border-box` to the element. [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rkV34/) - I'll take a look at your other question later

Comment: aha. but now there is that 1 pixel of white at the bottom that I had when I first added the max-height transition.  I don't remember what I had done to get rid of it but now its back

Comment: update, its not a white pixel, it's transparent.  I'll work on it.