# Overflow hidden hides dropdown, but taking overflow hidden off hide navigation background

Tags: html, css

First off, here's a .js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B6DSv/

The issue I am having is with my .css:

```
nav {
    overflow: hidden; /*THIS LINE*/
    background-color: #004b98;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and here:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">teadsfasdfadsst</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If I take off `overflow: hidden;`, the dropdown works... But my background is taken off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the children elements are floated (taken out of the document flow), the parent element, `nav`, collapses upon itself; thus, the background isn't shown because `nav` has a height of `0`.

Rather than using `overflow:hidden` to fix this, just add a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) to the element instead:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/PmP29/)

```
nav:after {
    content:'';
    clear:both;
    display:table;
}
```

Comment: any chance you could tell me if/how this could be implemented to solve [my similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550856/multilevel-nav-menu-not-showing-3rd-level) about needing `overflow:hidden`but not wanting it??

Comment: @ChrisM I'll take a look at both of your questions

Answer (score 1):

Clearfix will help

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

http://jsfiddle.net/B6DSv/1/

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: It would help, but it's much easier to clear after each nav element, as I must clear anyway.