# 1 unexplained transparent pixel at bottom of dropdown nav menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

this is sort of a continuation of [this solved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550856/multilevel-nav-menu-not-showing-3rd-level).
as you can see [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkV34/) the 3rd level dropdown is working but the fix has created this unexplainable single pixel transparent border at the bottom of the dropdowns.  You can see it if you look closely between the dropdown and the box-shadow.

html:

```
<nav id="menu" class="dark_menu">
    <!-- Main Nav Start -->
    <ul id="main-nav" class="clearfix">
        <li id="port" class="parent menu-item"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>

            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li id="regular" class="parent menu-item"><a href="#">Regular</a>

                    <ul class="clearfix">
                        <li id="menu-item-1036" class="menu-item"><a href="#">4 columns</a>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-1033" class="menu-item"><a href="#">3 columns</a>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-1030" class="menu-item"><a href="#">3 columns w/ sidebar</a>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-1029" class="menu-item"><a href="#">2 columns</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="2col" class="parent menu-item"><a href="#">Ajax</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-1727" class="parent menu-item"><a href="">About</a>

            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li id="menu-item-870" class="menu-item"><a href="">Who We Are</a>

                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-872" class="menu-item"><a href="">What We Do</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul {
    padding-left:0px;
}
#menu {
    position:relative;
    border:none;
    height:auto;
    top:34px;
    left:0px;
}
#menu ul {
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#menu li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:25px 26px 17px;
    border-bottom:3px solid transparent;
    margin-right:1px;
    color:#6B6B6B;
    font:11px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block;
}
#menu > ul > li:hover > a {
    color:#F15A2B;
    border-color:#F15A2B;
}
#menu > ul li.selected > a, #menu > ul li.selected:hover > a {
    color:#3B3B3B;
    border-color:#3B3B3B;
}
/* Submenu (second level) */
 #menu li > ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:auto;
    left:0;
    width:180px;
    max-height:0;
    box-shadow:1px 2px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index:99999;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    background: inherit !important;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: 216px;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
#menu ul li > ul:hover {
    overflow:visible;
}
#menu li > ul li {
    height:36px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #EEE;
    padding-top:0;
}
#menu li > ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
#menu li > ul li a {
    background:#FFF;
    padding:11px 15px;
    height:35px;
    color:#999;
    width:100%;
    font:10px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block;
}
#menu li > ul li:hover > a {
    color:#FFF;
    background:#F15A2B;
}
#menu li > ul li.selected > a, #menu li > ul li.selected:hover > a {
    color:#3B3B3B;
    background:#FFF;
}
/* Submenu (third level) */
 #menu li > ul > li > ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:0 !important;
    left:180px !important;
    width:180px;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow:1px 2px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
    visibility:hidden;
}
#menu li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
#menu li > ul > li > ul > li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
#menu li > ul li ul li a {
    background:#FFF;
    padding:11px 15px;
    height:35px;
    color:#999;
    font:10px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block;
}
#menu li > ul > li > ul > li:hover > a {
    color:#FFF;
    background:#F15A2B;
}
#menu li > ul li.selected > a, #menu li > ul li.selected:hover > a {
    color:#3B3B3B;
    background:#FFF;
}
/* Dark Menu */
 #menu.dark_menu li ul li {
    border-color:#464646;
}
#menu.dark_menu li ul li a {
    background:#3B3B3B;
    color:#999;
}
#menu.dark_menu li ul li:hover > a {
    color:#FFF;
    background:#F15A2B;
}
#menu.dark_menu li ul li.selected > a, #menu.dark_menu li ul li.selected:hover > a {
    color:#FFF;
    background:#3B3B3B;
}
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a small black line at the bottom? What browser are you in?

Comment: chrome. it looks white in the fiddle but it's transparent. its really prevalent in the [actual site](http://mtctinc.com) with the slider behind it. you can see it in firefox also

Comment: can see it better if we darken the shadows: http://jsfiddle.net/rkV34/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like adding the following CSS below fixes your issue. If you want to remove the border on the last item, you have to make sure the element does not extend past its child height which is the only element with the background color.

```
#menu li > ul li:last-child {
   border-bottom:none;
   height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the border on the last list item, colored or not. its pretty standard practice on a dropdown menu to remove the border from the last `li`

Comment: if you look at the fiddle with your solution, when you hover the last list item you see a border.  no good.  then I would have to add another rule-set to color the border on hover, clunky, then its actually 1 pixel bigger than the other list items.

Comment: Can I assume that your comment referring to my initial answer?

Comment: yes, it was a terrible answer. wrong and  unexplained.  this updated answer is much better and correct. muchas gracias

Comment: this has been bugging me for days and the explanation is so simple and stupid - css 101 - the box model! the `li` height was set to 36 with a 1px border, so when I removed the border, needed to change the height to 35. doh!

Comment: Haha yes, we all have those moments!